# What is the correct way to rebind a thrust pointer in thrust 11.5

Tags: c++, pointers, type-traits, thrust

I am using the CUDA thrust library inside a heavily templated library that depends a lot in template metafunctions to deduce related types.

In thrust 11.3, type `thrust::cuda::allocator<T>::pointer` yields `thrust::cuda_cub::pointer<T>`, for any `T` (for example `double`).

In turn I can use rebind to obtain the const version. That is, type `std::pointer_traits<thrust::cuda_cub::pointer<T>>::rebind<T const>` yields `thrust::cuda_cub::pointer<T const>`.

No surprises so far.

In thrust 11.5, `thrust::cuda::allocator<T>::pointer` yields a more complicated type `thrust::pointer<T, thrust::cuda_cub::tag, thrust::tagged_reference<T, thrust::cuda_cub::tag>, thrust::use_default>`, which is presumably equivalent to the old type.

The problem is that I cannot obtain the const version of this pointer in the usual way, because `std::pointer_traits<thrust::pointer<T, thrust::cuda_cub::tag, thrust::tagged_reference<T, thrust::cuda_cub::tag>, thrust::use_default>::rebind<T const>` yields what I know (by other means) that is an incorrect type: `thrust::pointer<T const, thrust::cuda_cub::tag, thrust::tagged_reference<T, thrust::cuda_cub::tag>, thrust::use_default>`.

(the tagged reference type should be `T const`).

**What is the correct way to obtain the const version of a thrust 11.5 pointer using rebind?**

**EDIT:** I opened and issue https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/issues/1629#issuecomment-1066331885

Comment: Honestly, that is so baroque... it's bad enough we have this stuff in the standard library. Anyway, I understand you've opened an issue against thrust on GitHub... that's what I would have suggested.

Comment: Baroque is the word. I own the templates library, so in principle i can do it in another way. Let me know if you know other way. Although i don’t want to add a hard dependency on thrust in the library itself… or perhaps it is inevitable given the complexity of thrust.

Comment: You're welcome to ping me in chat or email me if you'd like to explain what your library does. Personally I'm not a fan of thrust and have tried to take [other](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-kat/) [directions](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers). About this rebind'ing... are you sure that, under the hood, it's not simply all raw pointers?

Comment: @einpoklum I solved this with an ugly workaround by declaring and not defining a bunch of typedef. In any case, my library does multi dimensional array containers https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi. For GPU, GPU or for memory that fulfill certain minimal requirements. It was not trivial but now it mostly works with thrust. There is a overlap with your library which also provides arrays. If your library provides allocators, pointers and some algorithms (`[uninit_]copy[_n]`, `swap`, `equal`, etc) then I can plug it to my library or at least show how to use it combination with my library.